# How to efficiently move data from elasticsearch index (with one shard) to another index (with 5 shards)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index which contains around 5 GB of data on a single node in a single shard. Now I have created another index with same settings as older one, but with number_of_shards as 5 instead of 1.

I am looking for the most efficient approach to copy the data from older index to newer index without any downtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) for this. You could use the following configuration. Make sure to replace the source and target hosts, as well as the index and type names to match your local environment.

**File: reindex.conf**

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "localhost:9200"       <---- your source host
   index => "my_source_index"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "localhost"       <--- your target host
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   manage_template => false
   index => "my_target_index"
   document_type => "my_type"
   workers => 5
 }
}
```

And then you can simply launch it with

```
bin/logstash -f reindex.conf
```